# Manipulating JavaScript Unicode

Tags: javascript, unicode

In the JavaScript code below, the first prints the correct symbol (Greek gamma) while the second prints the string '\u03b8'.

```
var full_uni='\u03b8';
var part_uni='\\' + 'u03b8';
console.log(full_uni);
console.log(part_uni);
```

My questions are

1. Why?
2. How can I print `full_uni` as a '\u03b8' (or similar) and/or print `part_uni` as the correct symbol?

Comment: `var part_uni='\u03' + 'b8';` it will produce error

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti - yes it did!  I've altered it so that it works.

Comment: so thats your answer, both are different

Comment: Notice how you have `\\ ` in the second one? Unsurprisingly, `\\u03b8` will output as `\u03b8`!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - I had to add the second backslash otherwise the first would escape the closing single quote and it would complain bitterly.  Maybe I worded the question poorly.  Maybe I should have asked "How do I programatically generate unicode characters and how can I convert unicode back into hex for further manipulation?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there's no built-in way to go back-and-forth between them, you can make functions to do so.

```
function decodeUnicodeSequence(str) {
    return str.replace(/\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/ig,function(_,hex) {
        return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex,16));
    });
}
function encodeUnicodeSequence(str) {
    return str.replace(/[\u00a0-\uffff]/g,function(chr) {
        return "\\u"+("00"+chr.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4);
    });
}
```

Comment: I was half expecting a 'can't be done' as an answer.  It's strange that the langugage doesn't have a native way to convert between the two. Thanks for the alternative code though.

Comment: @garethTheRed I have literally never seen any need whatsoever to convert between the two before. I know languages sometimes have obscure functions, but something like this is just so... unneeded, most of the time. Besides, if the native language had everything, what would we need the ability to define our own functions for? ;)

Comment: For an online tool that converts between the two, see [_JavaScript escapes_](http://mothereff.in/js-escapes). It uses [the _jsesc_ JavaScript library](http://mths.be/jsesc) to generate the most compact escaped output possible.